# Zend Framework v1 INSERT INTO multiple rows

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Im working on E-Shops based on Zend Framework v1.12 and I need to create a parser of product list with thousands of records. I'd tried to make a loop of `createRow() -> save()` but I found it too slow with big lists.

Does Zend fr. have an functional to save multiply record in one query?

Answer (score 0):

No, Zend Framework v1 doesn't have such functional. But it's not so hard to make an implementation of INSERT INTO for your needs. Here is my function:

```
     /**
     *  @brief Safe implementation of INSERT INTO
     *  
     *  @param [in] $array Array[] of values 'column'=>'value"
     *  @return void
     *  
     */
    protected function saveRows($array) {
        $values=$columns    = array();
        $vLabels=$cLables   = '';

        foreach ($array as $colval) {
            $vLabels.="(";
            foreach ($colval as $column=>$value) {
                if (!$ready) {
                    array_push($columns,$column);
                    $cLables.='?,';
                }
                array_push($values,$value);
                $vLabels.='?,';
            }
            $vLabels        = rtrim($vLabels,', ');
            !$ready     ?  $cLables = rtrim($cLables,', ') : null;
            $vLabels       .= "),";
            $ready          = true;
        }
        $vLabels = rtrim($vLabels,', ');

        $query="INSERT INTO `".$this->primary_key."` (".$cLables.") VALUES ".$vLabels;
        $subst=array_merge($columns,$values);
        $this->query($query,$subst);
    }
```